# How to make two Java maps with same keys, removing entries from the first for keys not present in the second

Tags: java, treemap

I have two `TreeMap` like,

```
fisrtMap{
"2022": "11",
"2023": "22"
}

secondMap{
"2022": "33"
}
```

I want to make the `firstMap` like,

```
fisrtMap{
"2022": "11"
}
```

I mean, I need to remove uncommon keys from maps.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: `firstMap.keySet().retainAll(secondMap.keySet());` removes from `firstMap` keys not present in `secondMap` (assuming your map can be modified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use a special `Set` of keys from both `Map` objects

The solution applies to any modifiable `Map` class, not just the [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) class you mention.

As [commented by Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75761737/how-to-make-two-treemap-with-same-keys-java#comment133647549_75761737), your can do this by way of  **a set of keys of each map**.

First set up some sample data. We make a modifiable map `x` by using `Map.of` literals syntax for convenience.

```java
Map < String, String > x =
        new HashMap <>(
                Map.of(
                        "2022" , "11" ,
                        "2023" , "22"
                )
        );

Map < String, String > y =
        Map.of(
                "2022" , "33"
        );
```

Get a view on the keys of map `x` as a set. Then remove any entries in that map where the key is not present in a second set, a set of keys from the second map.

```
x.keySet().retainAll( y.keySet() );
```

That call to [`Map::keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) returns a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) view of the keys contained in the map. **That set is special**, in that it is connected to the map from which it came. To quote the Javadoc:

> The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map

Dump to console the before and after state of our map `x`.

```java
System.out.println( "x = " + x );
x.keySet().retainAll( y.keySet() );
System.out.println( "x = " + x );
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/7fR8gc).

```
x = {2023=22, 2022=11}
x = {2022=11}
```

---

By the way, if that first part of your data is meant to be a calendar year, you could make use of the `java.time.Year` class.